# Why would medieval sleeper agents gather in one place?

Tags: warfare, medieval, organizations, espionage

I am making a system of sleeper agents that work to support an invasion. This all takes place in a late-medieval Chinese-inspired setting, on a large island nation (let's say "Keiza") that another, more industrialised country ("Hamia") is planning to invade.

**The agents**

The agents are young men who have been recruited out of the local populace. They must locate themselves in strategic places, along major roads, important mountain passes, etcetera. Some agents move to the proper town, though most are recruited where they will be needed.

Once recruited, they are assets to Hamia for the coming invasion. They live docile lives, get employed, get married, and await instructions from headquarters. Those instructions will come through the mail (which is quite reliable in this world) and encoded in what looks like casual correspondence. Every agent has their own encryption/decryption code memorised, and they can act on the instructions.

**Passive phase**

There's two phases to the invasion plan. In the first "passive" phase, any actions carried out by the agents must be completely inconspicuous. They are mostly gathering information to support the planning of the Hamian invasion. For example, they can report on troops moving through their towns (being located on strategic routes), they can try to get jobs cleaning dishes for the war strategists and listen in on meetings. They then communicate their findings, also via encrypted correspondence over the mail system.

Now this post does not go directly to the foreign nation - it travels through other agents and eventually to a port city where a coordination center is located. They can sneak information out of the country and bring new instructions in from the Hamian war ministry.

**The invasion**

The second phase of the invasion is the date of the actual invasion, when the Hamian army lands. That is when each agent is to carry out local sabotage, as much as they feasibly can accomplish as individuals. They should burn down bridges, try to trigger avalanches in mountain passes, they should cut all the horses loose and poke holes in every ferry. This naturally exposes them, and it also cripples the postage system that was their only way of acquiring instructions, so this is coordinated exactly. Their only remaining instructions after the invasion properly begins, are to flee the country and travel to Hamia, where they receive a generous pension as war heroes.

The Hamian army should land and march in virtually unopposed. The Keizan army would be crippled by the broken infrastructure, whereas the Hamians would know exactly which bridges have not been burned down and can plan their routes accordingly. They should be able to take over a good portion of the country before its domestic military can organise a response.

**Other details:**

- The setting is a late-medieval Chinese-inspired setting, but not Earth. The horse is the primary mode of transportation, and th
- Keiza is very big (the size of core China), but culturally, religiously, and geographically diverse. The citizens do all share a language and writing system. It is loosely governed, the government is decentralised (though with war on the horizon the army is organised).
- Keiza is an island and the invasion is aquatic; that is why it can come by surprise.
- Hamia is more industrialised and they have explosives - they don't have the monopoly but they can manufacture them in large amounts. In the general populace (either country) explosives are rarely used for applications like mining. Gunpowder-based firearms (aside from big unwieldy cannons) do not exist.

**The problem**

That is the sleeper agent network, to the extent I have it figured out. What I need is, as a natural part of this network and the invasion plan, is a time - or several times - when many sleeper agents may be found in one place. That sounds counter-intuitive - why would sleeper agents who do their best to live calm lives in the countryside gather up? Still, that is a crucial aspect for the story that this system ultimately serves. Ideally up to dozens of people would gather, though not necessarily every agent at once. They can go to some remote place along the coast.

To clarify: the reason to have them gather should not be derived from random circumstance or plot (e.g. one of the agents happened to die and all the others were invited to his funeral). I need a systematic reason, as a part of a rational plan to best utilise the agents, being able to be planned in advance and arising from the way these sleeper agents function and the opportunities we can expect them to have. If this invasion happened a thousand times in a thousand different ways, then such a gathering should still happen basically every time.

Any tweaks to this system as described can be made as long as the aesthetic remains the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130825/discussion-on-question-by-keizerharm-why-would-medieval-sleeper-agents-gather-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for an organisational structure that would make gatherings of low-level operatives necessary.

I would suggest making a slight adjustment to your original idea: The low-level agents do not know who they are working for and do not look for specific information in the 'passive stage'. They report everything. Then reports are analysed in Hamia by specialists.

This adjustment will allow a cell-based structure where low-level people do not know their superiors, do not know the goals of the organisation, and ideally do not know that any organisation exists in the first place.

1. Recruitment

Different people can be recruited under different pretences. Some are just 'friends' who exchange news. Some are 'trade secret spies'. Some are thugs. And so on. You can pick whatever works the best with your setting and characters. The important point is that new recruits have no idea that they are being recruited.

Merchants are great if your setting is close to China. Merchants could travel more or less freely, had access to a lot of information, and wealthy merchants had a lot of connections with the officials.

2. 'Passive' stage

At this stage recruited individuals share information with recruiters. Recruiters should also help as many of these individuals as possible to get some benefits. For example, a merchant can get a timely credit or a recommendation letter, a thug may get a better job. The main idea is to make these people feel indebted and, when appropriate, collect information for future blackmail.

3. Gathering

After months or years of mutually beneficial relationships, all these people are invited to a gathering. Some may receive an invitation to visit their friend's vacation home, some may receive news about an exciting employment opportunity, possible business deal, etc. Again, you can choose whatever works the best with your setting and story.

The purpose of the gathering is to test the recruits, weed out double agents, and make them loyal to Hamia. The latter is the reason for help mentioned in 2.

Another goal of the gathering is to make adjustments to the plans after proper assessment of the new agents, their capabilities, and their loyalty. A merchant who is too scared to plant a bomb still can be useful in some other ways, for example, they can supply spoiled foodstuffs or low-quality equipment to the Keiza's military.

Special equipment can also be distributed during this gathering. It is also a good opportunity to get invaders' people into the right positions. For example, a merchant may bring a new hire or a new concubine. None of these will raise any questions.

Once everyone and everything is in place, it is time to proceed with the active phase per your initial plan.

Comment: I was afraid that the question will be closed before I can post my thoughts. So it is a bit rushed. Please feel free to ask for clarifications or elaborations if you need any. Even if the question is closed I will be able to edit my answer. (And I hope that my head works fine now :) )

Comment: I have to apologise for my slow response. The meta debate on whether invasions can be asked about at all has burned me out a little, but I really appreciate your contributions both there and to my specific scenario.

Comment: Your suggestion for the purpose of the gatherings (gauging every agent and assigning corresponding tasks) is excellent. Works very well with the loose, temporary nature of the network. Large gatherings themselves may very well make them more complicit, give them the idea they are part of a community (revolutionaries?) rather than actual spies working for a foreign power. I can attest that your head is in fine shape :-)

Comment: @KeizerHarm I am glad I could be helpful. And no worries, I understand that the WB.SE can be frustrating sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to drop one piece of your current setup: As it is now, the agents are briefed, and there is exactly one message that they are able to receive - the 'Go at Date dd.mm.yy'. This makes them completely undetectable (they may be findable, as in, a good detective could suss them out from commonalities in their origin (all settled in the same year, all had some weird funds to settle them in, etc), but their actual day-to-day behavior leaves them un-detectable. They could not even be recalled or retasked.

So i suggest you drop the Go-Signal, and make this a more chatty outfit: They communicate with their liaison, or with their agency at home via letters: Give them troop counts, troop movements, advise on how much work is to be done there, whether more agents might be needed in the district, updates on their cover, etc. This they achieve with one-time pads, something inocuus like the spacings of the words on a very common religious screed. The one-time pad was designed to last them until the invasion, but either someone got very verbose, or the invasion got put on the back burner, either way, the one-time pads need replenishing. They cannot just do the same key-cover again, so the new key will need to be something else - the way to operate will differ, and this is not something explained in a few words in a coded message.

The agents will need to come in and have a workshop on the utilisation of their new key. Cue the heroes, who now stumble upon all those weirdos in the woods, each with a peculiar piece of cloth that has some very weird miss-weaves... or something. If you need multiple of these meetings, just have the keys run out every once in a while. One-time-pads are very ineffective information-wise (ideal cryptographically, but very long in relation to the coded message), so it is absolutely thinkable that in a very unliterate society it would be simply too weird and obvious to have a 100 000 word document lying around. If the key is 1000 bit, after 1000 bit of message it is done. Cue the next meeting.